# Dependent source while calculating Thevenin's voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]In this case how and why while calculating the thevenin's voltage a dependent source plays a part but a resistor in its place have no contributions? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculated the voltage across the 8 ohm resistor correctly, but then you assumed that the voltage at nodes a and b is the same as the voltage across the 8 ohm resistor...but they are not the same. There is a voltage across the dependent voltage source, which you must consider.

Find the voltage across the dependent source, then use KVL to find the voltage across a and b.

Comment: the branch that contains the dependent source is open circuited if there was a resistor we ignore the resistor but here why do we consider the dependent source in that open circuited branch

Comment: You don't really **ignore** the resistor...you note that in the open-circuit case there is no current flowing through the resistor and therefore **no voltage** across the resistor. You still need to satisfy KVL around the loop that includes the 8 ohm resistor and nodes a and b.